# Converting all object columns to float except for one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say in the dataframe df there is:

```
 a     b    c    d
ana   31%  26%  29%
bob   52%  45%  9%
cal   11%  6%   23%
dan   29%  12%  8%
```

where all data types under a, b c and d are objects. I want to convert b, c and d to their decimal forms with:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
```

but I don't know how to not include column a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `update` with `to_numeric`

```
df.update(df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x.str.rstrip('%'),errors='coerce'))/100)
df
Out[128]: 
     a     b     c     d
0  ana  0.31  0.26  0.29
1  bob  0.52  0.45  0.09
2  cal  0.11  0.06  0.23
3  dan  0.29  0.12  0.08
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop.html) for all columns without `a` with [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), convert to floats and divide by `100`:

```
cols = df.columns.drop('a') 
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('%', '', regex=True).astype('float') / 100.0 
print (df)
     a     b     c     d
0  ana  0.31  0.26  0.29
1  bob  0.52  0.45  0.09
2  cal  0.11  0.06  0.23
3  dan  0.29  0.12  0.08
```

Or you can convert first column to `index` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so all columns without `a` should be processing:

```
df = df.set_index('a').replace('%', '', regex=True).astype('float') / 100.0 
print (df)
        b     c     d
a                    
ana  0.31  0.26  0.29
bob  0.52  0.45  0.09
cal  0.11  0.06  0.23
dan  0.29  0.12  0.08
```